# How to export dsyMatrix

Tags: r, matrix, export, stata

I have a dsyMatrix that i need to export as one data set to stata's dta file. I wanted to use:

```
write.dta(X, "C:/Users/.../Desktop/X.dta")
```

but then, i need to convert dsyMatrix to data.frame. Is it possible, or is there any other way to export dsyMatrix?
Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`write.dta(as.data.frame(as.matrix(X)), "C:/Users/.../Desktop/X.dta")`

I'm not sure if there's a way to convert a dsyMatrix to data.frame directly.